# Understanding the Haskell as-pattern

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I'm reading through Real World Haskell, and am trying to understand the as-pattern.

From the book (Chapter 4):

```
suffixes :: [a] -> [[a]]
suffixes xs@(_:xs') = xs : suffixes xs'
suffixes _ = []
```

The book explains the @ symbol thus,

> "...bind the variable xs to the value that matches the right side of the
>   @ symbol."

I'm having trouble understanding this explanation.
Supposing I call

```
suffixes "hello"
```

Explicitly, what would the above line with the @ do to this (on the first iteration)? I know what the result of the function is, but cannot see how we get there from the above code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the "@" symbol mean in reference to lists in Haskell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153465/what-does-the-symbol-mean-in-reference-to-lists-in-haskell)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`xs'` would be bound to the string `"ello"`.

`xs` would be bound to the string `"hello"`.

The `@` pattern lets you give a name to a variable while also matching its structure and possibly giving name to the components.

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps an actual "de-sugaring" will make it easier to understand:

```
suffixes xs@(_:xs') = xs : suffixes xs'
```

is equivalent to

```
suffixes xs
 | (_:xs') <- xs   = xs : suffixes xs'
```

i.e. you're firstly binding the entire argument to the variable `xs`, but you also do pattern matching on the same argument (or, equivalently, on `xs`) to `(_:xs')`.