# Haskell - Adding a Tuple to a List of Tuples if not already existing else increase existing value of Tuple

Tags: haskell

I have a Tuple representing a Product:

`type Product = (String, Int, Float)`

String is the name, Int the amount and Float the price or value.

Now i want to do the following:
I got a List of Products and into that List i want to add a new Product.
But if the Product is already in the List i just want to increase the amount.
(For now i dont care what happens if the price/value is not the same)

"If already in List then increase amount of that Product. Else add it to the List"

Example Input: ("Beer", 9, 3) [("Beer", 1, 3),("Milk", 3, 3),("Tea", 10, 3)] 
Expected Output: [("Beer", 10, 3),("Milk", 3, 3),("Tea", 10, 3)] 
or 
Example Input: ("Apple", 2, 1) [("Beer", 1, 3),("Milk", 3, 3),("Tea", 10, 3)] 
Expected Output: [("Beer", 1, 3),("Milk", 3, 3),("Tea", 10, 3),("Apple", 2, 1)] 
(The List has no order so it does not matter where the new Product is inside the List)

`addProduct :: Product -> [Product] -> [Product]`

Sounds easy enough and actually i got a working method that does this:

```
-- check if a name is inside a List
nameInList :: String -> [Product] -> Bool
nameInList n [(a,b,c)]    = if (a == n) then True else False
nameInList n ((a,b,c):xs) = if (a == n) then True else nameInList n xs

-- add a product to a list if its not already in that list else just increase amount of that product
addProduct :: Product -> [Product] -> [Product]
addProduct (a,b,c) xs  = if nameInList a xs then newList else (a,b,c) : newList
  where newList = [ (a2,b2+b,c2) | (a2,b2,c2) <- xs, a2 == a ] ++ [ (a2,b2,c2) | (a2,b2,c2) <- xs, a2 /= a]
```

But i was wondering if i can somehow achieve the same using pattern matching and recursion. I also feel like it should be possible without another function that does some checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided you know your list of products will never have a duplicate name, this is indeed quite simple with pure recursion:

```
addProduct :: Product -> [Product] -> [Product]
addProduct p [] = [p]
addProduct product@(name, amount, price) (product'@(name', amount', price') : ps)
  | name == name' = (name, amount' + amount, price') : ps
  | otherwise = product' : addProduct product ps
```

(Notice that if the product is being added with a different price to the version currently in the list, this leaves the old price in place - I'll leave it up to your business requirements whether this is even possible and if so what should happen.)

Note the use of [as patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27467650/understanding-the-haskell-as-pattern) to allow the `product` tuples to be pattern-matched against while still retaining a way to refer to the whole thing in the recursive case. This isn't essential but makes the code much more readable. And also I've used guards rather than if-then-else - this is more of a personal preference but I think Haskellers generally prefer it this way.

A couple of small notes on your own code:

1. please use understandable variable names. You'll see I've replaced `(a, b, c)` with `(name, amount, price)` because this clearly explains to a reader what the  values actually represent
2. `if (a == n) then True else False` is redundant because it's exactly the same as simply `a == n`, so you should use the shorter, clearer version.

Comment: thanks thats exactly what i was looking for. Don´t know why i was not able to think of that solution it does not seem to complicated.

Answer (score 3):

If you represented them as a `Map` you can make use of the [`insertWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.4.1/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v:insertWith) function

```
insertWith :: Ord k => (a -> a -> a) -> k -> a -> Map k a -> Map k a
```

> Insert with a function, combining new value and old value. `insertWith f key value mp` will insert the pair `(key, value)` into `mp` if `key` does not exist in the map. If the `key` does exist, the function will insert the pair `(key, f new_value old_value)`.

This means you could implement it as follows, inserting what ever logic you want for the price

```
{-# Language BlockArguments #-}
{-# Language StandaloneKindSignatures #-}

import Data.Kind (Type)
import Data.Map (Map, insertWith)

type Product :: Type
type Product = Map String (Int, Float)

addProduct :: String -> (Int, Float) -> Product -> Product 
addProduct = insertWith \(amount1, price) (amount2, _) -> (amount1 + amount2, price)
```

or if you're fine with [`biliftA2`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-5.5.11/docs/Data-Biapplicative.html#v:biliftA2): `addProduct = insertWith (biliftA2 (+) const)`