# How can I bind the entirety of a pattern to an identifier in Swift?

Tags: swift, pattern-matching

I am recently doing a Swift project that involves a lot of pattern matching with enums that have other enums or tuples as associated values. For example:

```
switch something {
    case .someCase(.someOtherCase(let foo, let bar)):
        // do something with foo and bar...
        // Then,
        someFunction(.someOtherCase(foo, bar))
    // other cases...
}
```

Here are some minimal declarations for the above code to compile:

```
enum Bar {
    case someOtherCase(Int, Int)
}

enum Foo {
    case someCase(Bar)
}

func someFunction(_ bar: Bar) {
    
}

let something = Foo.someCase(.someOtherCase(1, 1))
```

The thing I don't like about this, is that I have to almost repeat `.someCase(.someOtherCase, foo, bar)` twice - once in the pattern, and once in the function call.

I would like to do something like this:

```
// made up syntax that doesn't compile :(
case .someCase(let nested = .someOtherCase(let foo, let bar)):
    // do something with foo and bar...
    // then:
    someFunction(nested)
```

This is similar to the [`@` pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27467650/understanding-the-haskell-as-pattern) in Haskell.

**How can I do this?**

If this were an if statement, I could do two pattern matchings:

```
if case .someCase(let nested) = something,
    case .someOtherCase(let foo, let bar) = nested {
    // do something with foo and bar...
    // then:
    someFunction(nested)
}
```

But I don't think that'd work in a switch statement, as a comma in a switch case means "or", not "and". I could obviously use another `if case`, but that just makes the code unnecessarily deeply nested. The entire switch case being an if statement that does another pattern matching seems really awkward too.