# Does Prolog have an alias "operator" like Haskell?

Tags: performance, haskell, prolog, alias

In Haskell, there is a language feature called "as"-operator (sometimes known as alias). The idea is the following: given you have a function that for instance takes as input a list and wants to return all tails, you can implement this as:

```
tails a@(_:xs) = a : tails xs
tails [] = [[]]
```

The `@` ensures that you have a reference to both the entire argument as well as a reference to some parts of the structure of the parameter. This is intelligent performance-wise (it is more a performance hack, because reconstructing an array `(x:xs)`) in the body of the first line, will - if not optimized by the compiler - result in allocating a new object, modifying fields, etc. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1153465/67579) for more information.

I was wondering if Prolog has something equivalent: for instance if you want to implement tails in Prolog, it can be done the following way:

```
tails([H|T],[[H|T]|TA]) :-
    tails(T,TA).
tails([],[[]]).
```

But it could be more efficient if there was an "as"-operator like:

```
tails(L@[_|T],[L|TA]) :-  %This does not compile
    tails(T,TA).
tails([],[[]]).
```

Is there any such construct, or a language extension?

Comment: In prolog you can avoid the alias. Just use `tails(L, [L|TA]) :- L=[_|T], ...`.

Comment: I agree, but it would be nice if this was possible in the head. (I know I'm being annoying :S)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Good idea<sup>1</sup>! The speedup appears to be limited to ~20% (for most list sizes).

In this answer, we compare three different predicates that differ regarding `@`-like data reuse:

```
list_tails([], [[]]).                % (1) like `tails/2` given by the OP ...
list_tails([E|Es], [[E|Es]|Ess]) :-  %     ....... but with a better name :-)
   list_tails(Es, Ess).

list_sfxs1(Es, [Es|Ess]) :-          % (2) "re-use, mutual recursion"
   aux_list_sfxs1(Es, Ess).          %     "sfxs" is short for "suffixes"

aux_list_sfxs1([], []).
aux_list_sfxs1([_|Es], Ess) :-
   list_sfxs1(Es, Ess).

list_sfxs2([], [[]]).                % (3) "re-use, direct recursion"
list_sfxs2(Es0, [Es0|Ess]) :-
   Es0 = [_|Es],
   list_sfxs2(Es, Ess).
```

To measure runtime, we use the following code:

```
:-( dif(D,sicstus), current_prolog_flag(dialect,D)
  ; use_module(library(between))
  ).

run_benchs(P_2s, P_2, L, N, T_ms) :-
   between(1, 6, I),
   L is 10^I,
   N is 10^(8-I),
   length(Xs, L),
   member(P_2, P_2s),
   garbage_collect,
   call_walltime(run_bench_core(P_2,Xs,N), T_ms).

run_bench_core(P_2, Xs, N) :-
   between(1, N, _),
   call(P_2, Xs, _),
   false.
run_bench_core(_, _, _).
```

To measure [wall-time](/questions/tagged/wall-time)<sup>2</sup>, we utilize `call_walltime/2`—a variation of [`call_time/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27823841/4609915):

```
call_walltime(G, T_ms) :-
   statistics(walltime, [T0|_]),
   G,
   statistics(walltime, [T1|_]),
   T_ms is T1 - T0.
```

Let's put above code variations to the test...

- ...using different list lengths `L`...
- ...and running each test a number of times `N` (for better accuracy).

First, we use [swi-prolog](/questions/tagged/swi-prolog) version 7.3.14 (64-bit):

```
?- run_benchs([list_sfxs1,list_sfxs2,list_tails], P_2, L, N, T_ms).
   P_2 = list_sfxs1, L*N = 10*10000000, T_ms =  7925
;  P_2 = list_sfxs2, L*N = 10*10000000, T_ms =  7524
;  P_2 = list_tails, L*N = 10*10000000, T_ms =  6936
;
   P_2 = list_sfxs1, L*N = 100*1000000, T_ms =  6502
;  P_2 = list_sfxs2, L*N = 100*1000000, T_ms =  5861
;  P_2 = list_tails, L*N = 100*1000000, T_ms =  5618
;
   P_2 = list_sfxs1, L*N = 1000*100000, T_ms =  6434
;  P_2 = list_sfxs2, L*N = 1000*100000, T_ms =  5817
;  P_2 = list_tails, L*N = 1000*100000, T_ms =  9916
;
   P_2 = list_sfxs1, L*N = 10000*10000, T_ms =  6328
;  P_2 = list_sfxs2, L*N = 10000*10000, T_ms =  5688
;  P_2 = list_tails, L*N = 10000*10000, T_ms =  9442
;
   P_2 = list_sfxs1, L*N = 100000*1000, T_ms = 10255
;  P_2 = list_sfxs2, L*N = 100000*1000, T_ms = 10296
;  P_2 = list_tails, L*N = 100000*1000, T_ms = 14592
;
   P_2 = list_sfxs1, L*N = 1000000*100, T_ms =  6955
;  P_2 = list_sfxs2, L*N = 1000000*100, T_ms =  6534
;  P_2 = list_tails, L*N = 1000000*100, T_ms =  9738.
```

Then, we repeat the previous query<sup>3</sup> using [sicstus-prolog](/questions/tagged/sicstus-prolog) version 4.3.2 (64-bit):

```
?- run_benchs([list_sfxs1,list_sfxs2,list_tails], P_2, L, N, T_ms).
   P_2 = list_sfxs1, L*N = 10*10000000, T_ms =  1580
;  P_2 = list_sfxs2, L*N = 10*10000000, T_ms =  1610
;  P_2 = list_tails, L*N = 10*10000000, T_ms =  1580
;
   P_2 = list_sfxs1, L*N = 100*1000000, T_ms =   710
;  P_2 = list_sfxs2, L*N = 100*1000000, T_ms =   750
;  P_2 = list_tails, L*N = 100*1000000, T_ms =   840
;
   P_2 = list_sfxs1, L*N = 1000*100000, T_ms =   650 
;  P_2 = list_sfxs2, L*N = 1000*100000, T_ms =   660
;  P_2 = list_tails, L*N = 1000*100000, T_ms =   740
;  
   P_2 = list_sfxs1, L*N = 10000*10000, T_ms =   620
;  P_2 = list_sfxs2, L*N = 10000*10000, T_ms =   650
;  P_2 = list_tails, L*N = 10000*10000, T_ms =   740
;
   P_2 = list_sfxs1, L*N = 100000*1000, T_ms =   670
;  P_2 = list_sfxs2, L*N = 100000*1000, T_ms =   650
;  P_2 = list_tails, L*N = 100000*1000, T_ms =   750
;
   P_2 = list_sfxs1, L*N = 1000000*100, T_ms = 12610
;  P_2 = list_sfxs2, L*N = 1000000*100, T_ms = 12560
;  P_2 = list_tails, L*N = 1000000*100, T_ms = 33460.
```

**Summary:**

- The *alias-thingy* can and *does improve performance* significantly.
- In above tests, the SICStus Prolog [jit](/questions/tagged/jit)<sup>4</sup> gives **10X speedup**, compared to SWI-Prolog!

---

<sup>**Footnote 1:** Why do the stunt of putting `(@)/2` in the rule head? 
To end up with non-[idiomatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_idiom%0A) Prolog code?

**Footnote 2:** We are interested in the total runtime. Why? Because garbage-collection costs show with larger data sizes!

**Footnote 3:** The answer sequence has been post-processed for the sake of readability.

**Footnote 4:** Available since [release 4.3.0](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/4.3.0/html/relnotes/4_002e3_002e0-New-Features.html). Current target architectures include [IA-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IA-32) and [AMD64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64).</sup>

Comment: I wonder if putting such thing in the head cannot lead to additional optimizations. For the `tails`, it is not really useful, but now you postpone checks that *could* have been done before calling that predicate. Nevertheless, impressive answer +1.

Comment: Furthermore I'm wondering whether the compiler could not be improved to spot that `[E|Es]` is used twice and thus construct an "implicit" alias itself.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem. Yes, in principle, Prolog compilers *could* do that. OTOH in a pure functional language with lazy evaluation (like Haskell) this is even more straight-forward. Prolog compilation is tricky, if you want to ensure that compiled and the analog interpreted code never **ever** behave any differently. Lots of subtleties/details need to be taken care of right. SICStus JIT is relatively new... and very impressive!

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem. Oh, and btw: optimization can be fun and a nice learning experience, but it should not be *the* main focus! Consider: http://www.prolog-heritage.org/en/ph4.html .