# Bind and Destructure block arguments

Tags: ruby

In ruby is there a way to simultaneously bind the argument of a block to a local as well as destructure it?

Googling hasn't found me anything and playing in IRB has been fruitless, but I thought I recalled functionality that would work similar to the following:

```
>> [[1, 2], [3, 4]].map{|x@(y, z)| [x, y, z]}
=> [[[1, 2], 1, 2], [[3, 4], 3, 4]]
```

Where `x` captures each top-level element of the iterated object (in this case first `[1, 2]`, then `[3, 4]`) and `y` and `z` capture the sub-elements of the object in inside of `x` (`1` then `3` and `2` then `4`, respectively).

#### Edit

It just occurred to me that the feature I projected into Ruby actually comes from Haskell: [What does the "@" symbol mean in reference to lists in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153465/what-does-the-symbol-mean-in-reference-to-lists-in-haskell)

Still, is there an elegant way to achieve the same in Ruby?

Comment: Can you explain what x y and z refer to here?

Comment: @maxpleaner tried to update the question, though I'm not sure I really helped the cause any

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'd want a solution that assigned [[1, 2], [3, 4]] to x, [1, 2] to y and [3, 4] to z

How about this:

```
irb(main):001:0> y, z = x = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
=> [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
irb(main):002:0> y
=> [1, 2]
irb(main):003:0> z
=> [3, 4]
irb(main):004:0> x
=> [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

**Update (Let's put this into a block)**

Is this okey for you:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]].tap do |arr| 
  y, z = x = arr 
  p x # => [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
  p y # => [1, 2]
  p z # => [3, 4]
end
```

Comment: Good thinking, but I don't know if answers the question.

Comment: Yes! But now how well can we put this into a block?

Comment: BTW, you don't _need_ an extra variable `arr`. Just `.each {|x| y, z = x; ... }`

Answer (score 1):

How about this?:

```
2.3.0 :003 > x, (y, z) = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
 => [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
2.3.0 :004 > x
 => [1, 2]
2.3.0 :005 > y
 => 3
2.3.0 :006 > z
 => 4
```

or this?:

```
2.3.0 :007 > x = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
 => [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
2.3.0 :008 > y, z = x
 => [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
2.3.0 :009 > y
 => [1, 2]
2.3.0 :010 > z
 => [3, 4]
```

or, if you really wanted to combine them all into one statement (though that might be less clear):

```
2.3.0 :011 > y, z = (x = [[1, 2], [3, 4]])
 => [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
2.3.0 :012 > x
 => [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
2.3.0 :013 > y
 => [1, 2]
2.3.0 :014 > z
 => [3, 4]
```

I may not understand what you want to do; I don't think `map` is what you want because that performs the same operation on all elements in the input array, and you're mixing whole array and array element operations.  Here's a method that *may* do what you want, I don't know...

```
2.3.0 :017 > def f(x)
2.3.0 :018?>   y, z = x
2.3.0 :019?>   yield x, y, z
2.3.0 :020?>   end
 => :f
2.3.0 :030 > f([[1, 2], [3, 4]]) { |x, y, z| p x; p y; p z }
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
```

Comment: Using your example, I'd want a solution that assigned `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]` to `x`, `[1, 2]` to `y` and `[3, 4]` to `z`.

Comment: Similar to @scorix's answer, this will both bind and destructure, but it's also outside the context of a block.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a custom array method which gets the job done:

```
class NestedArray < Array
  def each(&blk)
    super { |array| blk.call(array, *array) }
  end
  def map(&blk)
    super { |array| blk.call(array, *array) }
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
nested_array = NestedArray.new([[1,2],[3,4]])
nested_array.each do |x, y, z|
  puts "#{x}#{y}#{z}"
end
# result:
# [1, 2]12
# [3, 4]34
```

The additional arguments are optional, i.e. you could still write

```
nested_array.each { |x| puts x }
```

and it will still work, even though you are choosing not to use the `y` and `z` arguments.

Comment: Thanks! While you do show a solution to my problem using `NestedArray`, the part about hashes treating block arguments differently than arrays seems wrong. I believe the example you give of a hash works identically to the array of arrays.

Comment: you're right, I removed the wrong / irrelevent section.