# What does the expression `first @ (x:xs) ` and `second @(y:ys)` mean?

Tags: haskell

I saw a snippet of Haskell code that recursively joins two list together, while sorting it in an ascending order:

```
merge :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge [] xs = xs
merge ys[] = ys

merge first @ (x:xs) second @(y:ys)
   | x <y = x :merge xs (y:ys)
   | otherwise = y : merge ys (x:xs)
```

I do not understand what this line `merge first @ (x:xs) second @(y:ys)` does.

Comment: If you're wondering about the use of `@`, see [*What does the “@” symbol mean in reference to lists in Haskell?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1153465/2751851)

Comment: The spacing in your snippet is super unidiomatic and misleading.

Comment: @duplode dont still understand, can you break it down?

Comment: You would normally write the left hand side as `merge  first@(x:xs)  second@(y:ys)` as this is more readable. It is  similar to `merge  (x:xs)  (y:ys)` , except this allows you, in the right hand side, to use `first` as a shortcut for x:xs, and `second` as a shortcut for y:ys.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the "@" symbol mean in reference to lists in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153465/what-does-the-symbol-mean-in-reference-to-lists-in-haskell)

Comment: @MikaelF it is a bit confusing as I am a beginner

Comment: @jpmarinier i think I understand now, my main issue now is what is  `(x:xs) (y:ys)`, I know `:` put adds a number to the start of the list, does the same apply to `(x:xs) and (y:ys)`

Comment: Since `first` and `second` are not used in the body of the function, you can get rid of `first@` and `second@` altogether

Comment: @Oto-ObongEshiett `(x:xs)` uses the `:` constructor to pattern-match on the list. The first element of the list gets assigned to `x`, while the remainder of the list is assigned to `xs`. As you have already mentioned, you can also use the `:` constructor to put `x` and `xs` back together to get the list `(x:xs)`; pattern-matching is just the reverse process.

Comment: @Oto-Obong Eshiett - Well, yes, exactly. And when a function takes a list argument, you have to allow for two patterns. The argument list can be either empty, that's the `[ ]` pattern. Or, it can be non-empty, and that's the `x : xs` pattern. Naïve definition of function length: `length [ ] = 0`  and on another line:  `length (x : xs) = 1 + (length xs)`

Answer (score 4):

Simple way to find out is to try it in GHCi (the GHC interpreter). If you run:

```
$ ghci
Prelude> functionName bind@(first:rest) = print(bind ++ ", " ++ [first] ++ ", " ++ rest)
Prelude> functionName "test"
"test, t, est"
```

We see that if we invoke `functionName`, what we get is:

```
bind  => test
first => t
rest  => est
```

So we can say:

1. `bind` takes the whole argument sent,
2. `first` takes head of the argument; first element of the argument,
3. `rest` takes everything except first element of the argument.

Comment: This is a nice way to provide quick understanding!